# When I change the state of a variable another one change without calling it in laravel's livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have this issue: [Imgr video issue](https://imgur.com/pLy0uLd)

The logic of the code is the next (I'm using livewire `3.1.0`):
I have two components

- `Table Component`
- `Modal Component` (is attached to the `Table Component`)

Table Component

```php
// Blade
<div>
    // ...
    <button wire:click="openModal">Open Modal</button>
    
    @if($showModal)
        @livewire('modal-component')
    @endif
</div>

// Logic
public $showModal = false;
public function openModal(){ $this->showModal = true; }

#[On('close-modal')]
public function closeModal() {
    $this->showModal = false;
}
```

Modal Component

```php
// Logic
public $departmentValue, $departmentId, $departmentDropdown = false;

public function toogleDepartmentDropdown(){
    $this->departmentDropdown = !$this->departmentDropdown;
}

public function setDepartmentDropdown($id, $value){
    $this->departmentId = $id;
    $this->departmentValue = $value;
    $this->$departmentDropdown = false;
}

public function closeModal(){
    $this->dispatch('close-modal')
}
// Blade
<div>
    <button wire:click="closeModal">Icon Close Button</button>
    
    <button wire:click="toogleDepartmentDropdown">@if($departmentValue){{$departmentValue}}@else - @endif</button>
    @if($departmentDropdown)
        <div>
            @foreach(App\Models\Department::all() as $department)
                <button wire:click="setDepartmentDropdown('{{$department->id}}','{{$department->department_name}}')">{{$department->department_name}}</button>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

I don't know if I have to use `mount()` because I've used it but it doesn't work, so I don't know where I have to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a *wire:key* for each *<button>* in the *@foreach*:

```html
<button wire:click="setDepartmentDropdown('{{$department->id}}','{{$department->short_description}}')" wire:key="{{'dep-' . $department->id}}">
```

There is also an error in

```php
$this->$departmentDropdown = false;
```

that should be

```php
$this->departmentDropdown = false;
```

Comment: It doesn't work because when I execute the function of `toogleDepartmentDropdown` and I click again to change the `departmentDropdown` state the Modal close because it change the value of the other component variable `showModal`, so it remaining the state of the on `true` permanently without calling the function `closeModal` that call a `dispatch('close-modal')` listener

Comment: I did a test with your code and it works perfectly for me. Maybe  there is some interaction with other components? Can you post the overall code?